# Show the congruence $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^{k+1}$ has exactly two solutions...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if $p$ is an odd prime, $p \nmid a$, and
>   the congruence
>
> $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^k$
>
> has exactly the solutions $x \equiv \pm t \mod p^k$, then the
>   congruence
>
> $x^2 \equiv a \mod p^{k+1}$
>
> has exactly two solutions, and that they  are of the form $  \equiv
> \pm(t + \ell \cdot p^k) \mod p^{k+1}$, where $\ell$ satisfies
>   the congruence
>
> $\ell \cdot 2t \equiv \frac{a - t^2}{p^k} \mod p. $

Hi, I'm stuck on this problem.

Comment: Have you studied Hensel's lifting lemma?

Comment: @hardmath we have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $q:=p^k$ and write $x=u\cdot q+t$ where $t<q$ and $u<p$, and take its square (modulo $p^{k+1}$).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I get $u^{2}q^{2} + 2uqt + t^{2}$, which is equal to  $u^{2}p^{2k} + 2utp^{2k} + t^{2}$
I don't understand what this means $\mod p^{k+1}$ though

Comment: Well, as $k\ge 1$, $\ 2k\ge k+1$, so $p^{2k}$ gives *remainder* $0$ modulo $p^{k+1}$, so that
$x^2\equiv 2uqt+t^2 \pmod{p^{k+1}}$. Now, given $a$ and $t$, such that $t^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$ we are looking for $u$ with which $x=uq+t$ satisfies $x^2\equiv a\pmod{pq}$.

Comment: ahh ok, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Berci This allows us to obtain a solution modulo $p^{k+1}$ from a solution modulo $p^{k}$, but how do we know that there are only $2$?